# How to get json output in nvarchar, in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I used this Query to convert the data to JSON

> SELECT *FROM tbl_subject FOR JSON AUTO

Iam getting the response as [image]

when i click the response it is opening as XML file

[image]

how to change this xml to nvarchar data type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, in SQL Server, JSON is not a data type in itself (XML is), but just a string representation.

What you see is due to how SQL Server Management Studio handles JSON when returned as a resultset. It is NOT xml, SSMS just slaps on an `.xml` file type, and prettifies the result. If you were to change how results were returned (Tools|Options|Query Results|SQL Server|General), you'd see it something like so:

```
JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
---------------------------------------------------------- 
[{"RowID":1,"UniversityID":1,"AcademicID":4,"CourseID":1}]
```

But this is just how SSMS returns result. If you were to execute your statement from an application, the result would be of string data type.

You could also change how you execute the query, to something like so:

```
DECLARE @nres nvarchar(max) = (SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_Subject FOR JSON AUTO)
SELECT @nres
```

Hope this helps!